# Pattern match numbers/operators

Tags: java, regex

Hey, I've been trying to figure out why this regular expression isn't matching correctly.

```
    List l_operators = Arrays.asList(Pattern.compile(" (\\d+)").split(rtString.trim()));
```

The input string is `"12+22+3"`

The output I get is `-- [,+,+]`

There's a match at the beginning of the list which shouldn't be there? I really can't see it  and I could use some insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically, there is an empty string in front of the first delimiter (first sequence of digits). If you had, say a line of CSV, such as `abc,def,ghi` and another one `,jkl,mno` you would clearly want to know that the first value in the second string was the empty string. **Thus the behaviour *is* desirable in most cases.**

For your particular case, you need to deal with it manually, or refine your regular expression somehow. Like this for instance:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(rtString);
if (m.find()) {
  List l_operators = Arrays.asList(p.split(rtString.substring(m.end()).trim()));
  // ...
}
```

Ideally however, you should be using a parser for these type of strings. You can't for instance deal with parenthesis in expressions using just regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

That's the behavior of split in Java. You just have to take it (and deal with it) or use other library to split the string. I personally try to avoid split from Java.

An example of one alternative is to look at [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from Google Guava.

Answer (score 0):

Try Guava's [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

```
Splitter.onPattern("\\d+").omitEmptyStrings().split(rtString)
```